# serialize into a json object

Tags: jquery

My jQuery is a bit rusty and cant remember how to generate json objects. Im trying to create the below json from my serialize method but it doesnt fill the tags with anything else then two values?

```
function serializeObject() {
    var o = {};
    o["CompanyTemplateId"] = CompanyTemplateId;
    o["Tags"] = [];
    $("[id^=DQTag]").each(function () {
        o["Tags"].push({'TagKey': $(this).id, 'TagValue': $(this).value});
    });

    return o;
};
```

What I would like it to look like:

```
   {"CompanyTemplateId": "1",
    "Tags":[
            {"TagKey":"news1","TagValue":"This is a news item from tagValue."},{"TagKey":"news2","TagValue":"Second value"}
           ]
    }
```

The result i get is :

```
 {"CompanyTemplateId":"1","Tags":[{},{}]}.
```

The number of objects in the Tags are correct but why isnt there any key/value pairs?

Comment: see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery) to get an object to json conversion

Comment: Is there any reason why you are trying to serialize it yourself??? There is a pretty easy library for this https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. An object is a data structure, JSON is a notation system for representing that data structure in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out why it failed. It was because of me using `$(this)` instead of simply this.

wokring code:

```
o["Tags"].push({'TagKey': this.id, 'TagValue': this.value});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You are missing a `"` here:

```
"TagKey":"news1","TagValue":"This is a news item from tagValue.},
Quote missing here --------------------------------------------^
```

---

#### Or you can use this:

```
JSON.stringify(o, null, 2);
```

Comment: thanks for the missing ". I cant use JSON.stringify because of browser support.

Comment: @Marthin `JSON.stringify` is supported as far as IE8, are you working with 7?

Comment: IE 6 is in the requirements so yes. It´s for some realy old stuff that the customers dont whant to update. Dont know why but they told me it had to support IE 6 =(

Comment: @Marthin You can use Douglas Crockford's library to add `stringify` support cross browser.

Comment: +1 for using json2.js as fallback, it is the foundation for all the native browser JSON methods. Can add it using Modernizr or IE conditional comments

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this function. It seems to do what you want, also on IE9.

```
function() {
    var o = {};
    o["CompanyTemplateId"] = 123;
    o["Tags"] = new Array();
    $("[id^=DQTag]").each(function(i , e) {
        o["Tags"][i] = new Object(); {
            o["Tags"][i].TagKey = e.id;
            o["Tags"][i].TagValue = e.value;
        };
    });
    console.log(o.Tags.length);
    console.log(o);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
    return o;
};
```

Comment: this didnt work, got an exception when debugging with IE saying "Object doesn't support this action "

Comment: I understand my solution did not work earlier, please check again. http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/sxcCf/

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about browser support when serializing JSON, you can use [the JSON2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), which provides support cross browser. Include it and use `JSON.stringify` to serialize your objects to JSON or `JSON.parse` to decode JSON to objects.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$(this).id`, try `$(this).attr('id')`. For value either use `$(this).val` or `$(this).attr('value')`;